# Sitecore Analytics not being logged

Tags: sitecore, analytics, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-dms

Sitecore DMS database is not storing user visits after June 2012, I have checked connection string and analytic is also enabled, I can go to execute board and I can see all logs before June 2010, I have checked license and it shows "Sitecore.OMS" in the list but there is no "DMS" option available.

I did not see any analytic related errors in the log file, 2 analytic related files are also available in Include folder, How can I check why user visits are not being stored after June 2010?

following are the lines from log file

```
ManagedPoolThread #5 02:59:24 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Analytics.Tasks.SubscriptionTask
ManagedPoolThread #5 02:59:24 INFO  SubscriptionTask started.
ManagedPoolThread #5 02:59:24 INFO  SubscriptionTask done.
ManagedPoolThread #5 02:59:24 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Analytics.Tasks.SubscriptionTask (units processed: )
```

Comment: This means that somehow you disabled DMS long time ago, read this article to troubleshoot the issue:
http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/08/Troubleshooting-Analytics-is-Disabled-with-the-Sitecore-Customer-Engagement-Platform.aspx

Comment: I have fixed that now, In web.config file in <sites> section, each site had "enableAnalytics=false" i switched it to true and now it is working.